# Why I can't follow more than 600 users on Instagram from Android device?

Tags: instagram

I can't follow more than 600 users on Instagram from Android device, but Instagram's web interface allows me to follow more than 600; I followed 10 more users from web interface.

On mobile, when I tap "Follow", it says "Following", but then it immediately goes back to "Follow".

I have Instagram version 7.3 on Android Lollipop 5.0

My mobile's WiFi is working fine and I did not exceed their follow/unfollow or like/unlike limit per hour. I tried these solutions but none of them worked:

- Waited 1 week with no activity on Instagram, just viewed the feed
- Logged out > uninstalled app > restarted Android device > installed
  app > logged in

Comment: How many followers did you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instagram lifted the restriction on my account and now I'm able to follow more people from android. I did not contact them though but the restriction was auto lifted after few weeks.

There was a temporary restriction on the account for some unknown reason that is most probably only known to instagram tech team because I did not exceed their follow/unfollow or like/unlike limit.

During this period I found same complaints from other instagram users on internet.

Comment: Thank you for self-answering your question. Consider to [merge your accounts](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to get back the ownership of your question too.